# Caption in table is not shown. I am using IJBC template

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx, labels, templates

I am adding caption in the table of the document:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/rrtmhcmkgvqr

I am writing over the template of the IJBC template. The issue here is that when I add the caption to the table at line 279, the caption is not displayed.

How could I fix this?

The structure of the main code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ws-rotating}     % used only when sideways tables/figures are used
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}%aÑADIR COMENTARIOS
\def\bib{B\kern-.05em{I}\kern-.025em{B}\kern-.08em}
\def\btex{B\kern-.05em{I}\kern-.025em{B}\kern-.08em\TeX}

\begin{document}

\catchline{}{}{}{}{} % Publisher's Area please ignore

\markboth{Author's Name}{Paper Title}

\title{Encovering governing equation from temporal observation}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{here I have the first caption}
\label{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|lllllllllllllll|}
\hline
W11 & W12  & W13 & W21  & W22 & W23 & W31 & W32   & W33 & a1 & b1   & c1 & a2    & b2 & c2 \\ \hline
0   & 5.75 & -9  & 9.96 & 0   & 8   & 8   & -1.39 & 0   & 0  & 0.01 & 0  & -0.01 & 89 & 0  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your MWE, and after ignoring a couple of reported errors, the very wide table was produced with a caption.

Were you expecting a List of Tables which would also show the caption? If so, add `\listoftables` at the appropriate place after your `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I can obtain also the captions of the table, but only if I ignore the commands that include the IJBC template. I suppose that this is what you mean when you say that you "ignore a couple of reported errors".  The problem is that I can not ignore the commands of the IJBC, for example, I can not ignore  "\documentclass{ws-ijbc}
", or "\usepackage{ws-rotating}" . That is why I also sent the link of my work where you can check the additional .tex archives of the IJBC template.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz After spending a lot of time getting the `ws-rotating` package onto my system processing your MWE produces an output with captions but with a warning about `destination with the same identifier (name{table.1}) has been used`. Your MWE does not use `\documentclass{ws-libc}`. I think that I will leave it all up to you. --- GOM

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying that you were able to display the caption with ws-rotating package but without \documentclass{ws-libc}?

I think I found a solution when using \documentclass{ws-libc}. Changing the syntax for the captions (answer posted) hope for vote up

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
The ws-ijbc document class has a different syntax for typesetting tables and captions. You need to use this syntax:

```
\tbl{Here I have the first caption}{
  \label{TabSlide13_1}
  \begin{tabular}...
   ...
  \end{tabular}
}
```